# How to get calculations on json simple datasource (grafana)?

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to add calculations to a json simple datasource?

On graphite datasource I can add some calculation to a value e.g. avg or total of two targets or I can add an alias for some target. 
On json simple datasource specs, there are no suggestions.

Comment: were you able to connect the json datasource for raw data? How did you do that?

Comment: It was quite easy. Start with static json instead of dynamic results

Answer (score 2):

That would have to be implemented in the webapp that [simple-json-datasource](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) is getting the data from. There are no plans for adding any math calculations within the plugin but we have been considering adding support to do math on any result within grafana itself. https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3677